# Shellcode in C - What does this mean?

Tags: c, shellcode

I'm not really getting how this code does what it does:

```
char shellcode[] = "\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00"           
                   "\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00"                  
                   "\xcd\x80";                  

int main()
{
    int *ret;
    ret = (int *)&ret + 2;
    (*ret) = (int)shellcode;
}
```

Okay, I know:

```
int *ret;
```

sets a pointer of int.
and:

```
ret = (int *)&ret + 2;
```

sets the address of ret and 2 bytes (I think.)

But I don't get what this means:

```
(int *)&ret
```

I know what `&ret` means but not what `(int *)&ret` means.
Also, how does it execute the shellcode by assigning the value of `shellcode` to `ret`?

UPDATE:
What is the difference between:

```
(int *)&ret  + 2
```

and:

```
&ret + 2
```

Comment: Curious why so many downvotes... the shellcode looks pretty harmless.

Comment: what will happen if i run this. is this malware

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The 'string' `shellcode` contains some machine code of some sort.

The `int *ret;` defines a variable `ret` which is a pointer to an `int`.

The assignment `ret = (int *)&ret + 2;` makes `ret` point to a location the size of two `int` from its own actual location (or address); this is an address in the stack, presumably where the return address of the function (`main()`) is stored on the stack.

The assignment `*ret = (int)shellcode;` assigns the address of the shell code to the return address.  Therefore, when the `main()` function exits, the return address is the shell code, which does whatever it does instead of exiting the program normally.

The casts cover up a multitude of sins.  The code makes a large number of non-portable assumptions which are probably justified on the target environment but not necessarily anywhere else.

---

> What's the difference between: `&ret+2` and `(int *)&ret + 2`?

Type, mainly; this is one of the multitude of sins mentioned previously.  `&ret` has the type `int **` (pointer to pointer to `int`) instead of `int *` which is the type of `ret` itself.  Since `sizeof(int *) == sizeof(int **)` on all actual machines, the cast merely quells a complaint from the compiler (about assigning the wrong type of pointer to `ret`) without changing the numerical result.